# My scatter plot is only showing one part of the data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create data
N = 60
g1 = (0.6 + 0.6 * np.random.rand(N), np.random.rand(N))
g2 = (0.4+0.3 * np.random.rand(N), 0.5*np.random.rand(N))
g3 = (0.3*np.random.rand(N),0.3*np.random.rand(N))

data = (g1, g2, g3)
colors = ("red", "green", "blue")
groups = ("coffee", "tea", "water")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

for data, color, group in zip(data, colors, groups):
    x, y = data
ax.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.8, c=color, edgecolors='none', s=30, label=group)

plt.title('Matplot scatter plot')
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

None of the code before creating the pyplot figure can be changed. It seems like the for loop isn't working correctly. I'm not sure what the problem is. There aren't any errors.

Comment: Pretty sure you just need to indent `ax.scatter(x, y, ...)`

Comment: You overwrite x and y in your for loop, so they'll only ever contain the last value. Indent `ax.scatter` and it'll work.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!